# How to use select query with textbox value as compare wiith database DATE column

Tags: asp.net, select, sql-server-2012

My .aspx markup:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupButtonID="imgpopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox11" Format="MM-yyyy" DefaultView="Months" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

.aspx.cs code behind:

```
string text = "Textbox11.Text";

string s = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE MONTH(Date) = 09 AND YEAR(Date) = 2018";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, conn);
SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dr.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is the query I got everywhere on net, but I don't want to specify the fixed date.... I want to allow the user to select text and according to that date select query should work

Please help me with is problem, as I'm new here.

Please forgive me if I asked the same question again which was asked previously by someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a parameterized query with an inclusive start date and exclusive end date for date range queries. It is best to avoid applying functions to SQL Server columns in a `WHERE` clause as that prevents indexes (if any) from used efficiently. For example:

```
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    if(!DateTime.TryParse(Textbox11.Text, out date))
    {
        //invalid date handing
        return;
    }
    var startDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);

    string s = "SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Date >= @StartDate AND Date < @EndDate;";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dr.Fill(dt);
```

Also, consider specifying an explict column list with only those columns needed rather than `SELECT *` as that will reduce unnecessary data transfer and give SQL Server more query optimization options.

Be aware that freeform date parsing is ambiguous. It would be better to restrict user input to a specific date format or use a date picker control that does that for you, allowing `TryParseExact` on the server side.

Comment: ya thats the one way ,we can do it....but what if when we want to do it for a particular selected date ?

Comment: For a single day, `var startDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day); var endDate = startDate.AddDay(1);`. You can similarly specify a time range like hour by using the overloads.